# Can I aggregate time series data between an on and off date using a data table join or the aggregate function?

Tags: r, data.table, time-series, aggregate

I would like to efficiently summarize continuous meteorological data over the periods that discrete samples are being collected.

I currently do this with a time-consuming loop, but I imagine a better solution exists. I'm new to data.table syntax, but it seems like there should be a solution with joining.

```
continuous <- data.frame(Time = seq(as.POSIXct("2019-01-01 0:00:00"),
                                    as.POSIXct("2019-01-01 9:00:00"),"hour"),
                         CO2  = sample(400:450,10), 
                         Temp = sample(10:30,10))

> continuous
                  Time CO2 Temp
1  2019-01-01 00:00:00 430   11
2  2019-01-01 01:00:00 412   26
3  2019-01-01 02:00:00 427   17
4  2019-01-01 03:00:00 435   29
5  2019-01-01 04:00:00 447   23
6  2019-01-01 05:00:00 417   19
7  2019-01-01 06:00:00 408   12
8  2019-01-01 07:00:00 449   28
9  2019-01-01 08:00:00 445   20
10 2019-01-01 09:00:00 420   27

discrete <- data.frame(on = c(as.POSIXct("2019-01-01 0:00:00"),
                              as.POSIXct("2019-01-01 3:00:00")),
                      off = c(as.POSIXct("2019-01-01 3:00:00"),
                              as.POSIXct("2019-01-01 8:00:00")))

> discrete
                   on                 off
1 2019-01-01 00:00:00 2019-01-01 03:00:00
2 2019-01-01 03:00:00 2019-01-01 08:00:00

discrete[, c("CO2.mean","Temp.mean")] <- 
    lapply(seq(length(c("CO2","Temp"))), function(k) 
        unlist(lapply(seq(length(discrete[, 1])), function(i) 
            mean(continuous[
                which.closest(continuous$Time,discrete$on[i]):
                which.closest(continuous$Time, discrete$off[i]), 
                    c("CO2","Temp")[k]]))))

> discrete
                   on                 off CO2.mean Temp.mean
1 2019-01-01 00:00:00 2019-01-01 03:00:00    426.0  20.75000
2 2019-01-01 03:00:00 2019-01-01 08:00:00    433.5  21.83333
```

This works, but when aggregating tens of continuous variables into hundreds of sampling periods, it takes a very long time to run. Thank you for your help!

Comment: please note that without a set.seed, it is not possible to reproduce the expected output as you are creating the input with `sample`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An option would be a nonequi join in `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(continuous)[discrete, .(CO2mean = mean(CO2), 
    Tempmean = mean(Temp)),on = .(Time >= on, Time <= off), by = .EACHI]
```

---

or with a rolling join

```
setDT(continuous)[discrete, .(CO2mean = mean(CO2), 
   Tempmean = mean(Temp)),on = .(Time = on, Time = off),
        by = .EACHI, roll = 'nearest']
```

Comment: Ideally I could deliver a vector (or list?) of colnames from the continuous dataset, but this works well, thank you